# Getting a list of items from SharePoint gives ids of 1, 2, 3 instead of actual id for item

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

What I'm trying to ultimately do is read the contents of a document I have on my SharePoint site. I'm having trouble getting the right item-id.

What is happening is when I get a list of items from a drive with

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteid}/drive/list/items
```

The ids for each item are 1, 2, 3, 4, and not the underlying item ids.

```
// GET /drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/content
// GET /sites/{siteId}/drive/items/{item-id}/content
```

I need to be able to get the proper item-ids so I can do the above, I'll take either... I understand that I can just use the web URL to get the object.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1, 2, 3, ... is actually right, but I need to get a list first

```
GET /sites/{siteid}/drive/list/items/{itemid}/driveItem/content
```

will get the contents of the item